# Error: Network Error: with axios.put method request multiple time to server. But then catch error

Tags: node.js, mongodb, reactjs, express, axios

I am totally new in react js. 
My proplem is when I use axios.put method in react side:
Here is a method in my React component:

```
commitAssign() {
  let memberIds = this.state.assignedList;
  // update the data
  const headers = {
    "Content-Type": "application/json"
  };
  axios
    .put(`/api/projects/${this.props.project._id}`, { memberIds }, headers)
    .then(res => {
      this.state.assignedList = [];
      this.props.onUpdate();
    })
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
}
```

Here is my route in express:

```
app.put('/api/projects/:id',(req, res) => {
  //update database
  res.redirect(`/api/projects/${projectId}`);
})
```

And when I run react ,It seem likes this :
[image: error]

It seems like axios.put make multiple request to the server and then get a error.
Moreover, the data that I PUT still save in database multiple time (same data).

Note that If I change the PUT method to POST , everything is good - no problem. And I have tested the server using POSTMAN , It is no problem as well.

Does anybody know what is the problem here when using PUT method?

I am using:
server dependencies:
    "body-parser": "^1.18.3",
    "cors": "^2.8.4",
    "express": "^4.16.3",
    "mongoose": "^5.2.6"
client dependencies:

```
"dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.18.0",
    "jquery": "^3.3.1",
    "react": "^16.4.2",
    "react-dom": "^16.4.2",
    "react-router": "^4.3.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.3.1",
    "semantic-ui-css": "^2.3.3",
    "semantic-ui-react": "^0.82.1"
},
"devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.26.3",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.5",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "css-loader": "^1.0.0",
    "file-loader": "^1.1.11",
    "style-loader": "^0.21.0",
    "url-loader": "^1.0.1",
    "webpack": "^4.16.4",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.1.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.1.5"
}
```

Edit:
Here is my server:

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var cors = require('cors');
var app = express();
app.use(cors());
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/teamApp_V1', {
    useNewUrlParser: true
});
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true
}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.get('/api/projects', (req, res) => {
    Project.find((err, allProjects) => {
        if (err || allProjects == null) {
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            res.json(allProjects);
        }
    });
});
//creact new project
app.post('/api/projects', (req, res) => {
    let newProject = req.body.newProject;
    Project.create(newProject, (err, newProject) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
        res.redirect('/api/projects');
    });
});
//show
app.get('/api/projects/:id', (req, res) => {
    let id = req.params.id;
    Project.findById(id).populate('listMember').exec((err, foundProject) => {
        if (err || foundProject == null) {
            console.log(err);
            res.redirect('/api/projects');
        } else {
            res.json(foundProject);
        }
    });
});
//edit project - assign member
app.put('/api/projects/:id', (req, res) => {
    let projectId = req.params.id;
    let memberIds = req.body.memberIds;
    Project.findById(projectId, (err, foundProject) => {
        if (err || foundProject == null) {
            console.log(err);
            res.redirect('/api/projects');
        } else {
            memberIds.forEach((memberId) => {
                console.log(foundProject);
                //update member id to project
                foundProject.listMember.push(memberId);
                //update project that this member is work for
                Employee.findById(memberId, (err, foundMember) => {
                    if (err || foundMember == null) {
                        console.log(err);
                        res.redirect('/api/projects');
                    } else {
                        foundMember.project.push(foundProject._id);
                        foundMember.save();
                    }
                })
            })
            foundProject.save((err) => {
                if (err) {
                    console.log(err);
                    res.redirect('/api/projects');
                } else {
                    res.redirect(`/api/projects/${projectId}`);
                }
            });

        }
    });
});
//delete project 



// employees
//index employee
app.get('/api/employees', (req, res) => {
    Employee.find().populate('project').exec((err, allEmployees) => {
        if (err || allEmployees == null) {
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            res.json(allEmployees);
        }
    });
});

//create new employee
app.post('/api/employees', (req, res) => {
    let newEmployee = req.body.newEmployee;
    Employee.create(newEmployee, (err, newEmployee) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            //do nothing
        }
        res.redirect('/api/employees');
    })
});

//edit employee


app.get('*', (req, res) => {
    res.send('Oops! Page is not found.');
});

app.listen(8081, process.env.IP, () => {
    console.log('server is running');
});
```

Comment: seems like it's a cors error, can you show the server code?

Comment: Hi, I have update my server.

Comment: yes, the network error is because of redirection, why don't you directly put*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Believe that Dat Tran's answer is correct mostly, but it doesn't include the code and it doesn't tell you which approach and how you should take it.

Anyway, this is happening because of redirection. Your code is resulting in an infinite redirect loop, which looks like the following in chrome:

[image]

Instead of redirecting when you hit errors/success, just send the json and then later on the UI when the json is received show the error/success content.

Change the method to something like this (note I've added comments):

```
app.put('/api/projects/:id', (req, res) => {
    let projectId = req.params.id;
    let memberIds = req.body.memberIds;
    Project.findById(projectId, (err, foundProject) => {
        if (err || foundProject == null) {
            console.log(err);
            res.json(err);
        } else {
            memberIds.forEach((memberId) => {
                console.log(foundProject);
                //update member id to project
                foundProject.listMember.push(memberId);
                //update project that this member is work for
                Employee.findById(memberId, (err, foundMember) => {
                    if (err || foundMember == null) {
                        console.log(err);
                        res.json({ someError: err }); // send an error msg. <====
                    } else {
                        foundMember.project.push(foundProject._id);
                        foundMember.save();
                    }
                })
            })
            foundProject.save((err) => {
                if (err) {
                    console.log(err);
                    res.json(err); // just like you did in app.get <====
                } else {
                    res.json(foundProject);
                }
            });

        }
    });
});
```

Comment: The problem isn't fixed all. all of the res.redirect in the code should be replaced. It's not correct to use res.redirect in the API. Should be some 4xx for not found or 5xx for server error.

Comment: @DatTran Sorry, i forgot to update all of them. Just fixed. also don't you think the logic is incorrect here? he was redirecting in a `forEach` lol.

Comment: I'm not sure about his logic. That's why I just mention the reason and solution.

Comment: Yes, Thank you. I have replaced all of the "res.redirect" to "res.json". About the logic, @DakshMiglani , Can you tell me more about your point ? That would be awesome if you can point out my other mistake.

Comment: @VuLe so you're actually doing `res.json` in a for loop, but you can only send `res.json` once. So instead of doing that in a for loop, do it outside the loop.

Comment: @DakshMiglani : so you mean that even the error we will send it after run all the loop?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is `res.redirect('/api/projects');`.

Your server return 302 which tell the axios to continue to trace the redirection and get the response from that. That's why it results in a infinite redirect loop.

please change `res.redirect` to something like `res.status(400).json({ message: 'whatever' })`. The API should never return a redirect, but a status code to let the client side know the call is success or not and determine by itself what to do next.

Your `catch` on client side will catch that error and do the redirect or whatever.

You can take a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes for reference about different status code.

Comment: Thank for your response. The problem is fixed now.